# How do I lock records in Rails 3 for a specific amount of time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql, pessimistic-locking

What I want to do is basically have a user obtain the lock on a record and have it for a specific amount of time so they can make changes to it, like wikipedia. So lets say a wikipedia article gives the user an hour to edit it before other users may edit it.

How could I achieve that with Rails 3? I have read up and found that pessimistic locking is what I should use for the lock. Given that... What kind of mechanism would I use for releasing the lock say after an hour?

My stack is Rails 3, Heroku, PostgreSQL.

Thanks for any answers and I love to see code if you can that would be so awesome!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a field called "editable_until":datetime and set a specific date (Time.now + 30.min f.e.) when creating your record. And simply query this field to find out if the user has the right to update the record or not.

```
class Post << AR
  before_validation :set_editable_time

  validate :is_editable

  def editable?
    self.editable_until.nil? || self.editable_until >= Time.now
  end

protected
  def is_editable
    self.errors[:editable_until] << "cannot be edited anymore" unless editable?
  end

  def set_editable_time
    self.editable_until ||= Time.now + 30.min
  end
end

Post.create(:params....)
=> <Post, ID:1, :editable_until => "2011-10-13 15:00:00">

Post.first.editable?
=> true

sleep 1.hour

Post.first.editable?
=> false
```

Comment: Corrected my posting, there was a wrong operator (&&, but it should be ..nil? ||). Your are welcome :)

Comment: One more question on this...does this mean that I don't actually need pessimistic locking at all for this problem?

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything further. One thing you could do is to change my methods to a validate callback... Would be nicer.. Know what I mean?

Comment: Timecop is useful for testing instead of `sleep`: https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

Answer (score 0):

## Here's an example that creates locks, but doesn't delete them.

I leave that up to you.

The locks do expire after an hour in this example, but to complete the app they should automatically be deleted on a successful update of a post.

### [working example](https://github.com/wenzowski/devise_example)

or read the

### [relevant commit](https://github.com/wenzowski/devise_example/commit/4bf12a1eac6f2602fc6737eda3b6efce17d7fd11)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [acts_as_lockable_by](https://github.com/tareksamni/acts_as_lockable_by) gem.

Imagine you have a patient (ActiveRecord) class that can only be edited by one user and it should be locked to this user till he decides to release it:

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_lockable_by :id, ttl: 30.seconds
end
```

Then you can do this in your controller:

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    if patient.lock(current_user.id) 
      # It will be locked for 30 seconds for the current user
      # You will need to renew the lock by calling /patients/:id/renew_lock
    else
      # Could not lock the patient record which means it is already locked by another user
    end
  end

  def renew_lock
    if patient.renew_lock(current_user.id)
      # lock renewed return 200
    else
      # could not renew the lock, it might be already released
    end
  end

  private

  def patient
    @patient ||= Patient.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```